# How to prove sufficient funds when entering the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds

[U.S. Customs and Border Protection web site](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/796/~/does-a-foreign-visitor-have-to-carry-a-certain-amount-of-money-to-enter-the) states that:

> Travelers visiting the U.S. must be able to prove to a CBP Officer that they have sufficient funds (i.e. credit cards, cash, travelers checks, money orders etc.)

If I have a US account at Bank of America and have transferred money in, can I show the CBP officer the monthly statement of BOA as a evidence?

Comment: Yes you can, the same way you can use that for a visa

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can.  If there's doubt about your statement being accurate, you can always log on to your online banking and show the officer that way (make sure you have this set up).  Alternatively, the officer could call the bank to verify.

Having credit cards is always helpful too, but not absolutely essential.

US CBP generally doesn't ask a lot of questions about finances unless there is some question of the visitor's motivation for visiting.  For a relatively short trip, the funds verification is simple and fast, if it even occurs.  (As a Canadian visitor to the U.S., I have never been asked about funds, just occasionally about where we are staying.)

Comment: "Alternatively, the officer could call the bank to verify." - a bank worth its salt won't verify this over the phone...

Comment: @JonathanReez If convinced that it's US Customs and Border Protection, I suspect it might, especially if the customer also got on the line to give specific consent.